# how to share data from my App A to my App B in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have two or more applications.
one of them is the base application and the others are just extensions(add-on).
i want when user install base Application and after that user install other extensions of applications, some features be enable in my base app. something like Go launcher App. if u want to use go launcher themes you should install themes and you will allow to use themes in go launcher app.
is it possible in android?
if it is what do u suggest?
thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: go through [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Content Provider to achieve your task.

This example contains two applications like parent and child. it performs data sharing, database in parent application and child can access parent database using content provider.

Refer This Link: http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.V4STZjVazDc

[image]

Comment: is it possible app1 use app2 components ? components like activities,frgaments,layout. i mean when app2 installed , activities,layout and fragments... of app2 can be added to app1.

Comment: myself its not possible, because content provider cant support like this.

Answer (score 0):

aidl meet your needs ! App1 call App2 method use binder

Comment: is it possible app1 use app2 components ? components like activities,frgaments,layout. i mean when app2 installed , activities,layout and fragments... of app2 can be added to app1.